# Is it possible to have multitouch library in android with gesture builder or is onTouchEvent is the only way out?

Tags: android, multi-touch, hidden-markov-models

Is it possible to have multitouch library in android with gestureBuilder or is onTouchEvent is the only way out? There are so many apps in android supporting multitouch, do they create their own libraries for gesture detection in multitouch?

Answer (score 4):

I know it's a bit late to answer, but in order to others know. `GestureBuilder` only allows one touch. As you say, multitouch is easily detected via `TouchEvent`.